# kustomize: create configMap from a file in a different Git repository

Tags: configmap, kustomize

I know that I can use Kustomize's configMapGenerator to create a configmap from a file that resides in the same Git repository as the "kustomization.yaml" file.

For Example:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - config-file.json
```

But is it possible to create a configMap from a file that resides in a different Git repository?

For example:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-config
  files:
  - git::ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/proj/repo-name.git//config-file.json
```

Comment: Not AFAIK. If you can create a kustomization file in the remote repo, you could use it as a "remote base" though and it would work.